# Appending the content of old csv into new csv

Tags: python, csv

I created a function and the idea is that if the "main" file (transactions_ledger.csv) doesn't exist I need to create it and append the new file (user input- which file) to it.

The code is working BUT the new file has an additional row in between with no contents.

**note: I can not use pandas**

In advance thank you for helping me.

Here is my code and the output:

````
from csv import writer
import os
from operator import itemgetter

# Create the ImportFunction
def ImportFunction():

    # First step is to ask the user what file they would like to import
    which_file = input("Which file would you like to import?")
    #Second step is to load the file into python. For this I will use the With open statement in a try except block so the program doesnt crash if the file doesnt exist
    try:
        # i need to preform all actions! 
        with open(which_file,'r') as file:
            user_file = file.read()
            print(user_file)
            
    except:
        print("Sorry the user file can't be found. Please try again.")
    
    #Third step is to open the transaction_ledger.csv. If the file doesnt exist create it if it does then preform actions
    try:
        #Have to do this using append method
        with open('transaction_ledger.csv','r') as file:
            file_content_transaction_ledger = file.read()
            print(file_content_transaction_ledger)
    except:
        #Open user file and read it to be able to append to the new empty file transaction_ledger.csv
        with open(which_file,'r') as old_file:
            reader_obj = csv.reader(old_file) #read the current csv file
            
            with open('transaction_ledger.csv', 'w') as new_file:
                writer_obj = csv.writer(new_file, delimiter=",")
                
                for data in reader_obj:
                    #loop through the read data and write each row in transaction_Ledger.csv
                    writer_obj.writerow(data)
        print("New file created and filled in with old file data")  

ImportFunction()

with open('transaction_ledger.csv','r') as file:
    file_content_transaction_ledger = file.read()
    print(file_content_transaction_ledger) ```

**Here is the output:**

Which file would you like to import? transactions_q1.csv
9547632,Arasaka,3/1/2022,6500,PENDING
1584037,Militech,3/15/2022,3000,COMPLETE
9433817,Arasaka,4/1/2022,450,COMPLETE
9462158,Arasaka,4/29/2022,900,PENDING

New file created and filled in with old file data
9547632,Arasaka,3/1/2022,6500,PENDING

1584037,Militech,3/15/2022,3000,COMPLETE

9433817,Arasaka,4/1/2022,450,COMPLETE

9462158,Arasaka,4/29/2022,900,PENDING
````

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I need to specify inside the writer_obj = csv.writer(new_file,delimiter=",") the following:

`lineterminator = "\n"`